# explain how vector of pointers can be initialized and deleted properly

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a C++ code for a minimum Heap. I want to create a vector of pointers and make sure that they are properly deleated.

I am able to create a vector of pointers, however I get an invalid conversion error from the default constructor. Why is this the case?

Also, I am trying to write a user defined destructor to ensure that I don't have any memory issues. However, I can't figure out why I am getting an error that the pointer was not allocated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A(int av, int bv):a(av),b(bv){}
  int a, b;
};

struct Heap
{
   Heap() : ptr(new std::vector<A*>()) {}  //WHY AM I GETTING AN ERROR FOR THE DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR AND NOT THE CONSTRUCTOR BELOW?
   //ERROR: invalid conversion from ‘std::vector<A*, std::allocator<A*> >*’ to ‘long unsigned int’
   //ERROR: initializing argument 1 of ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(size_t, const _Tp&, const _Alloc&) [with _Tp = A*, _Alloc = std::allocator<A*>]’

   Heap(std::vector<A*> p) : ptr(p) {  //Works fine. 
       makeHeap();
   }

  ~Heap(){   //I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY I AM GETTING A MEMORY ERROR HERE
        std::vector<A*>::iterator it;
    for(it=ptr.begin(); it<ptr.end(); ++it)
    {  
      delete *it;
      *it=NULL;
    }
  }//ERROR:  malloc pointer being freed was not allocated  

  void makeHeap()
  {  //some code  }

  std::vector<A*> ptr;
  std::vector<int> heapLoc;
};


int main()
{
  A a0(2,5), a1(4,2);  
  std::vector<A*> aArray;  
  aArray.push_back(&a0);
  aArray.push_back(&a1);

  Heap h(aArray);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not new to C++ and I can't cope with a vector of pointers. My recommendation is: do **not** use a vector of pointers! If you really need to reference your object should use, at least, smart pointers.

Comment: A vector of pointers is not a pointer to a vector. That's why doing `new vector<A*>` (which yields a pointer) cannot be assigned to the vector member in your constructor. Also, you're deleting objects which were allocated on the stack, which will probably cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr` is a vector of pointers, not a pointer to a vector. So you can't use `new` to construct it on the heap and the store the address.

Instead, construct it like this:

```
Heap() : ptr() {}
```

This is call the default constructor for `ptr`, i.e. it will create an empty vector of pointers. You should also consider changing the name of `ptr` since it is not really a pointer.

---

Regarding your destructor (Dietmar has meanwhile posted an answer, and before him Cameron a comment, that explains it (+1 for that), but for the sake of completeness): you are getting a memory error because the pointers you store in your vector refer to addresses of objects you created on the stack. Specifically, the objects you create here:

```
int main()
{
  A a0(2,5), a1(4,2);  // <-- automatic storage, so they
                       //     will be deallocated automatically
  /* ... */
}
```

If you want your `Heap` object to be responsible for its own objects, you should have your constructor create objects on the heap that the destructor can then delete. One way of doing this is to define the copy constructor of `Heap` as follows:

```
Heap(const std::vector<A*> &p) : ptr() {
  std::vector<A*>::const_iterator it(p.begin());
  for ( ; it != p.end() ; ++it)
    ptr.push_back(new A(**it));
}
```

Your destructor can be used as-is then, but you may want to use `!=` instead of `<` in the for-loop.

```
~Heap() {
   std::vector<A*>::iterator it;
   for(it=ptr.begin(); it != ptr.end(); ++it)
   {  
     delete *it;
     *it=NULL;
   }
```

Finally, I am not sure if you really need a vector of pointers (rather than a vector of objects), but if you think you do, consider using smart pointers (e.g. C++11 offers `std::unique_ptr`, so you could define a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` to get around many of the allocation related problems).

Comment: Sorry, I did not elaborate on why I needed a vector of pointers. I just pointed out why in my comment below addressed to Dietmar Kuhl. I've been working on this code for days. I know I'm slow and it should be a simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Why am I getting an error foro the default constructor and not the constructor below?

```
ptr(new std::vector<A*>())
```

This is because operator `new` returns a *pointer* to `std::vector`, not a `vector` itself. Since you are declaring a `vector` as an object, you should simply remove the whole `ptr(...)` part: the `ptr` will be initialized correctly by the compiler.

A more modern approach is to use `unique_ptr<T>` in place of "raw" pointers. This will ensure proper destruction automatically when the `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Since people haven't pointed it out: When you destroy the `Heap` with the pointers to the stack, i.e., object not allocated on the free store (I was about to say "heap" but this might cause unnecessary confusion...) you'll get funny behavior as well. This entire approach is doomed from the start: Do **not** use a container of raw pointers unless your **really** know what you are doing! (even then you are probably best off not using a container of raw pointers)

Comment: `@Dietmar Kuhl` Can you help me design a better structure for my code then please? Let me try to explain what I am trying to do. 

I want to create an array `aArray` of objects `A`. In my code, I want create a minimum heap for the members `A.b` that meet a certain criteria (i.e., `A.a>3`). I want to be able to modify the value of `A.a` and `A.b` and use functions like `sortHeap, popHeap, pushHeap` to reflect these changes. Can you please suggest the best approach? Thank you.

Comment: @namu: Have a look at the [priority queues](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/heap.html) from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/): A collection of heaps I had submitted was one of the starting points for Boost and although the heaps which are there now don't seem to be based on my implementation they have a fairly similar interface. In any case, you don't want to store pointed to objects in a heap anyway: changing the priority of an object requires updating its position and you need the opposite direction, i.e., a handle to the object in the heap not the other way around.